# Browser Ball demo - How was this done

Tags: html

Back in 2009, there was a cool demo called [Browser Ball](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/browser-ball/).

The point of the demo was that the page opened several new overlapping browser windows and displayed a bouncing ball, that was smoothly transitioning between the windows as it was bouncing. Therefore the page had to be able to somehow

1. get information about the configuration of the browser windows on viewer's desktop
2. communicate between the windows

Sadly, the site where it was hosted now seems to be down. Does anybody know how it worked? How the communication between windows was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between windows can be managed through [`window.opener`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp).

The position of browser window can be determined using:

- `window.screenLeft` and `window.screenRight` in IE
- `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` in everything else.

For more information on browser window position in JS see:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenx.asp

Comment: why window.opener and not postMessage?

Comment: window.postMessage is intended for communication over different domains although I suppose it could be used for this.